# Programmatically executing a Google Contacts search in the browser

Tags: browser, contacts, google-apps

I have written an application that successfully searches for a Google Apps contact using the Google Data API, based on input from a user.

What I would REALLY like to do, however, is to programmatically execute a search in the Google Mail/Contacts application in the browser, rather than just retrieve the data for the contact(s) that match the search criteria.

Is there a way to do so?  I have not found anything in any of the Google API's about how to do this, and looking at the page source for the contacts page doesn't make it clear to me.

--sk.